# Wildcard capture in Java, unable to call a method

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, wildcard

I currently have three classes and trying to implement Generic Visitor pattern  for putting it into a library shared among all our projects:

```
public interface Visitable<ReturnType> {

    public ReturnType accept(Visitor<?, ?> v);

}

public interface Visitor<SomeVisitable extends Visitable<?>, ReturnType> {

    public ReturnType visit(SomeVisitable v);

}

public class BaseObject implements Visitable<Void>{
    public Void accept(Visitor<?, ?> v) {
        v.visit(this); //1
                       // The method visit(capture#1-of ?) in the type                                        
                       // Visitor<capture#1-of ?,capture#2-of ?> is not
                       // applicable for the arguments (BaseObject)
    }
}
```

Why did I get the compile-time error at `//1`? Honestly I really don't know what I should redisign in that code to make it compile.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. To be useful, the Visitor interface should have one visit() method per subclass of BaseObject. So it shouldn't be generic.

Comment: Did you try `? extends BaseObject`?

Comment: @JBNizet You mean that Visitor implementation shouldn't be generic at all, huh? If so, let me disagree with you, because if we put all these staff in a library we would write more readable and simple code and avoid creating those boilerplate classes. Wouldn't it be good?

Comment: You can make a generic car, but if it doesn't have any wheel or engine, it will be useless. Learn what the visitor pattern is about, and you'll realize making it generic ruins the point of using the pattern.

Comment: This is a great example of how design patterns are "half-baked" solutions and require effort to be applied. Their benefit comes at a cost of code complexity. Another way to think about this is with some humility: the Visitor pattern has been documented since at least 1995 (that's 20+ years). If such a generic solution were possible, then wouldn't it already be in the Java API, say, like Observer?

Comment: @JBNizet Well, that what I'm actually doing. Visitor pattern's main benifit is to allow us adding operation to some class without modifying existing code but with adding some. But it comes with kind of problems. The first one is cyclic dependencies. Any visitor should depend on all visitable classes in order to compile. In turn, the root visitable class depends on the visitor which makes it depending on its own subclasses. The reason why I was trying to put some boilerplate code into a library was reducing of maintining it. One question: Do you yourself use this pattern in production code?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Srsly? I'm using Java 7 an have not seen any generic observer implementation.

Comment: @user3663882 I do use it in production code, yes. So I know that each visitor interface is different from the other ones, precisely because it needs one visit() method per subclass of the visitable class to be useful, making a generic Visitabor interface impossible to implement.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for explanation. And one more question: You said that it's impossible to implement Generic visitor in Java. The reason is the fact that we cannot distinguish two generic type in runtime, huh?

Comment: No. The reason is what I just explained. For a FruitVisitor, the interface needs a visit(Banana) and a visit(Apple) method. For a VehicleVisitor, it needs a visit(Bike), visit(Car) and visit(Truck) methods. There's no way to meke that generic.

Comment: @JBNizet So, such implementation is impossible only in Java. In C++, it could be implemented just fine. Here is a [**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cbf780572cba96a). I also suspect that in C# it could be imlemented too. Thank you for the clear explanation anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is evidently the use of wildcards. Your `accept` method in `BaseObject` is accepting a visitor of type `Visitor<?, ?>`.

If you think about it, now the compiler has to fill in the gaps in the `Visitor` interface with these wildcards:

```
interface Visitor<? extends Visitable<?>, ?> {
   ? visit(? v)
}
```

Those gaps being filled are the so-called wildcard captures.

Now, you try to invoke `visit(this)`. How in the world can the compiler know if the type of `this` is the actual type being represented by your wildcard `?`?

As @JBNizet was explaining, the magic behind the visitor is the fact that it knows, at compile time all possible alternatives of objects being visited. I really doubt that using a `Visitor<?,?>` is a good idea here.

The solution to your problem consists in using actual type arguments and not wildcards in your visitor declaration as far as I can tell from your code example.